# How to get sent Emails Info?

Tags: android, email

I am developing one application related to Email.

I am geting inbox mail info by using the fallowing code .

```
private void initProtocol() {
        EmailAuthenticator authenticator = new EmailAuthenticator(account);

        Properties props1 = new Properties();  
        props1.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");  
        props1.setProperty("mail.host", stmpHost);  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        props1.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");  
        smtpSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props1, authenticator); 

        Properties props2 = new Properties();
        props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        imapSession = Session.getInstance(props2);
    }   
    public void getInboxMails() throws MessagingException {
        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);

        inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

        for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {

             Part p = messages[i]; 
            try {
                String subject = messages[i].getSubject();
                Log.v("info","subject="+subject);





            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return ;
    }
```

It is working fine.

But i want to get sent mail info.

If any body know the solution how to get sent mail info .

Please help me ,thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check Mailbox table. If there is an entry for SENT then you can fetch sent mails info just like INBOX mails (that you've done already). Android native email app makes these folders dynamically. So SENT folder doesn't exists until you send any email from your device.